# Too long text Displayfor Razor

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc

I'm doing an ASP.NET MVC website and I have a little question about Razor.

I'm using an

> @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.description)

To show the description of a product. But if the description is really long like :

> This description is really long and I don't want to scroll to see the
>   end of it

It's really awful to scroll to the right to see the end of it...

How can I do to have a display like this :

> This description is really
>
> long and I don't
>
> want to scroll to see
>
> the end of it

Can I do it with displayfor ?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Put it inside a `<div>` element styled with a width (side note: `DisplayNameFor()` will return `"description"` so I assume you mean `DisplayFor()`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

**CSS**

```
.wordwrap{
white-space: -moz-pre-wrap !important;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
white-space: -webkit-pre-wrap; /*Chrome & Safari */ 
white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
white-space: pre-wrap;       /* css-3 */
word-wrap: break-word;       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
word-break: break-all;
white-space: normal;
}
```

**View**

```
<div class="wordwrap">
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.description})
</div>
```

Comment: There is not overload of `DisplayNameFor()` (or `DisplayFor()` which is what OP really means) that accepts `htmlAttributes` (the method just renders text, not html elements)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I just tried it and it seems to do nothing :(

Comment: @JamieR It's better now :) Thank you very much !